# system.webserver/rewrite/allowedservervariables cannot be read beacuase it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2016

I'm getting this error though I've install URL rewrite module 2.

[image]

[image]

But IIS doesn't show URL reqrite

[image]

Comment: That means the installation failed. Check MSI log to see if you get more info.

Comment: Allow variable is not allowed by web.config. Please try to install URL rewrite manually and set applicationhost.config <section name="allowedServerVariables" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />

Comment: I installed URL rewrite on the server again though it is installed, then I could see URL rewrite in IIS manager and was able to install the software with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed URL rewrite on the server again though it is installed, then I could see URL rewrite in IIS manager and was able to install the software with no issues.